# How to fix error " The printer driver cannot connect to the network print server"

Tags: printer

### Scenario

We have a Label printer it's an Intermec PF8t that we are sharing over network. The Label printer is connected USB to a Windows XP machine and that machine serves as the printer server. The printer is shared over a TCP/IP port.

On the other end of the chain I got a user on a windows 7 64 bit machine that I want to connect to the Label printer. That was done successfully by going to start button, devices and printers, add printer, and adding the shared label printer from there.

The problem I want to get rid of is that when the user prints to the label printer it keeps showing this error:

> The printer cannot connect to the network print server.
>
> You may either try again to connect, or disable network features. If you disable network features , you can turn them on again later in the Network Settings dialog.
>
> Without connectivity, features like bidirectional coomunication and configuration sharing will not be available. Press the help button for more information and possible solutions.

Right now as temporary fix we just click disable and the user can prints his labels no problem. But this error is starting to get really annoying. Since my user can print successfully I was wondering if there wouldn't be a way to possibly disable that error message, either by disabling a not needed service or even through registry or anything I just don't want this error popping for my user anymore.

Comment: Did you try going into the Properties for that printer and see if you can disable the network features - or go into the "Network Settings" dialog it's talking about and try disabling "network features" from there?

Comment: I disabled the bidirectional communication option found in the ports tabs of the properties window will see if that change anything. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with a Datamax-O'Neil label printer that's connected via Ethernet and hosted off a Windows Storage Server 2008 R2 (print server), and I resolved the issue using the following steps:

- On the *print server* I selected *Properties for the printer (queue)* in question.
- Select the *Tools* tab.
- There is a *Driver Options...* button I selected.
- In the *Driver Options* window I selected the *Network Settings* tab.
- I then checked off box *Bidirectional Communication* under the *Network Features* section and this did the trick.

I no longer get the dialog box with the error message when I connect to the printer from a Client PC.  Hopefully this helps anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same thing happen. I'm sharing a Zebra label printer connected to a Windows 7 machine with a computer running Vista. 
I also got the message about disabling network features. I clicked to disable and I have not received the message again, the other user can print just fine.
I think it has something to do with security because some printer options are disabled. This is actually good because I don't want the user to mess up any of the advanced printer settings. 
In the printer properties window, under the security tab, you can control who can print and who can also manage the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you put the driver on the computer that the printer is not connected to ie:printer is connected to windows 64 bit machine and the computer you want to share it with is Vista 32 bit, you will need to add the 32 bit driver to the "additional drivers" box then connect to the printer on the vista machine that fixed the same error I read here